# Asp.Net Mvc: What is the best way to share script/style files in class libraries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for how to share script/style files in class library between Asp.Net Mvc projects.

I know that a lot of posts asking similar questions have been already within the stackoverflow.
But I was not sure that they are what I'm looking for.

I don't have much experience of .Net, and Asp.Net Mvc.
Just I want to achieve things like webjars that redistribute web resources as a class library.

I'm developing a class library that helps to resolve common concern in our products.
It includes razor partial views and razor layouts. They refer some stylesheet files and javascript files. So I would like to put them into the class library.

I thought to put the files into the class library as embedded resources, an  tags with a url needs to be located in my web page, and a program for the url have to return the embedded resources as a content file.

What I don't know is such program has already existed, or not.
I think It is a very common issue, hence I guess that .NET has already provided things like that. But I could not find it out in the google.

I got some information regarding ScriptManager. It seems to be a component to use with Web Forms. Although I suppose to be able to port ScriptManager to Asp.Net Mvc, I don't know how to use ScriptManager anyways.

I also got some information to specify a url in script tag converted from web resource path.
It looks very easy and correct way. But I'm not sure that a url to an embedded resource in class library will be resolved.

Please tell me how to achieve it.

Comment: Doesn't really have to be a compiled resource. You can use NuGet (via either a private feed like [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/) or a local folder) to share the same CSS, images, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Tieson.
What you are saying is to deploy js/css onto NuGet server, and to configure the common library to refer the js/css nuget package, aren't you? I can imagine that I can distribute them together.
I would keep your idea, but I would like to wait another idea.

Comment: Doesn't have to be published to NuGet. You can load packages from a local folder.

Comment: O.K.. I mean NuGet is just a package server, not official NuGet server. I could understand your idea.
Then could you tell me what kind project type to develop & distribute js/css only?